# look like vs looks like

Tags: grammar

https://www.lingq.com/en/learn-english-online/courses/165129/lesson-29-slapstick-431425/

But it's funny because it makes the intentional joke look like an unintentional one.

Why in the above sentence there is "look like" not "looks like"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use a verb after 'make', we use the base (infinitive) form, like these examples:

> it makes the intentional joke **look** like an unintentional one.
>
> John made his son **eat** his vegetables.
>
> I made my mother **cry** with joy when I graduated.

This also applies to the verb 'let', e.g. 'I let my daughter play with a ball'.

[How to use make (and let)](https://english-at-home.com/grammar/make-and-let/#:%7E:text=In%20English%2C%20the%20verbs%20%E2%80%9Cmake,the%20infinitive%20without%20%E2%80%9Cto%E2%80%9D.&text=But%20in%20the%20passive%20form,before%20she%20could%20go%20out.)